# jQuery Toggle hidden div based on a href link # or by new bio div

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I am trying to cleverly toggle a div.  Not sure the best (less code) way to do it with jQuery.  What I have is a page with speakers' images and their name/title.  Then a hidden div with their bio. Upon clicking the speaker's image I want the bio to display... the way I have it all bios show up :[

I ideally would like the links and the hidden bio to be automatically associated with each other vs updating ID.  So an example:  If link 1 is click show child or sibling (not sure here) of link bio. Here is the code...

```
<div class="speaker_container clearfix">
    <div class="speaker_img"><a id="speaker1" href="#" class="toggle_me"><img src="127.gif" alt="Speakers" /></a></div>
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <p>Title</p>
    <div class="speaker-bios clearfix">
        <p>Hidden Bio with css display.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="speaker_container clearfix">
    <div class="speaker_img"><a id="speaker2" href="#" class="toggle_me"><img src="123.gif" alt="Speakers" /></a></div>
    <h3>Title of Speaker</h3>
    <p>Alexius Doe Title</p>
    <div class="speaker-bios clearfix">
        <p>Hidden Bio with css display.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want the bio to appear with an effect as fade or slide?

Comment: Slide open would be best - thanks for asking.

Comment: This is what I was working on that fails - $('.toggle_me').on('click', function(evt) {$( ".speaker-bios" ).toggle("slow");});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('.speaker_container').on('click','.speaker_img',function(){ // it mean on click over '.speacker_img' that is inside each '.speaker_container'
    $(this).siblings('.speaker-bios').toggle("slow"); // it mean will find a sibling of this '.speaker_img' you clicked, called '.speaker-bios' and you toggle it.
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTxg7/

Comment: This is 100% perfect.  Thanks for the explanation too.